# Unable to get data in View MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am very new in MVC and trying to display some data in view but unable to do it.
I am creating some dummy data (not picking it from db) in the Controller class and trying to see in the View.  My code is as follows:

Controller code:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
     public class FirstController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /First/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var item = new First(1, "ee");
            return View(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Model Code:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{

    public class First
    {
        private string _name;
        private int _Id;
        public First(int id, string name)
        {
            _Id = id;
            _name = name;  
        }
        public string name{
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name= value;
            }
        }

        public int Id
        {
           get { return _Id;}
            set { _Id = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<ul id = "menu">
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Name","Index","First")</li>
</ul>
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.First
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
Hell0
@{
    Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name);
}
```

Comment: IMO, there is no reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: Is `@RenderBody()` present in `_Layout.cshtml`?

Comment: Is the `Hell0` rendered on the page ?

Comment: @RenderBody() is present.

Comment: Hell0  is also there

Comment: Can you change the Html.DisplayFor to Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.name); ?

Answer (score 0):

try like that:

Index.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.First

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
},
<h2>Index</h2>
Hell0
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name)
```

or

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.First

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @:Hello
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name)
}
```

Regards,
Marcin